# Field required a bean of type that could not be found on Generic JPA DAO architecture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, genericdao

I am trying to define an architecture for my project on spring boot

What I have do is to create a generic Repository that extends from JpaRepository

```
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
}
```

After that, each EntityDao will extends from BaseRepository

```
@Repository    
public interface AuthorityDao extends BaseRepository<Authority, Long> {

        Authority findById(Long idRole);

        Authority findByRoleName(String findByRoleName);

    }
```

This is how I do it on the repository layer. At the Service Layer, I create a class named GenericService which implements IGenericService and I inject into it my BaseRepository:

```
@Service
public class GenericService<T, D extends Serializable> implements IGenericService<T, D> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("UserDao")
    private BaseRepository<T, D> baseRepository;
// implemented method from IGenericService
```

}

And each Service will extends from GenericService:

```
public class AuthorityService extends GenericService<Authority, Long> implements IAuthorityService {

    @Autowired
    GenericService<Authority, Long> genericService;
```

When I run the project, I get this error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:
Field baseRepository in fr.java.service.impl.GenericService required a bean of type 'fr.config.daogeneric.BaseRepository' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'fr.config.daogeneric.BaseRepository' in your configuration.

How can I solve this problem?

UPDATE:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("fr.java.entities")
@ComponentScan("fr.java")
@EnableJpaRepositories("fr.java")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@PropertySource({ "classpath:mail.properties", "classpath:ldap.properties" })
@EnableCaching
@RefreshScope
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainApplication.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.debug("Starting {} application...", "Java-back-end-java");

        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you update that Bean declaration code

Comment: it's clear in error message you need to have bean for autowiring

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because you create `GenericService` as a bean and trying to inject `BaseRepository` but Spring can't do that because it isn't clear by which classes `BaseRepository` is parametrised.

From my side I can suggest you to do next: at first you `GenericService` shouldn't be a bean, all his children will be the beans, your should remove injecting of `GenericService` in your children classes, they already extends of it. Your `GenericService` should be abstract and it can have abstract method `getRepository` which will use inside `GenericService`, and injection of repository will be done in `GenericService` children classes.

So you should have something like this:

```
public abstract class GenericService<T, D extends Serializable> implements IGenericService<T,D> {
    abstract BaseRepository<T, D> getRepository();
}

@Service
public class AuthorityService extends GenericService<Authority, Long> implements IAuthorityService {

    @Autowired
    BaseRepository<Authority, Long> baseRepository;

    public BaseRepository<Authority, Long> getRepository() {
        retrurn baseRepository;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. this is very clever but it doesn't work. it's cannot creating a bean of base repository. I got this error: Error creating bean with name 'baseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception

Comment: and what this nested exception is?